# Can't link pcre thru brew in max os yosemite

Tags: homebrew, react-native, watchman

When I install watchman using `brew install watchman`, it got this `Error: You must brew link pcre before watchman can be installed`. So I try `brew link pcre` and `brew link --overwrite pcre`, I just got 
`linking /usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.36...
Error: Could not symlink share/man/man3/pcre.3
/usr/local/share/man/man3 is not writable.`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sounds like there is a permission issue with /usr/local/share/man/man3 . Have you checked the folder permissions for this folder?

Answer (score 36):

By design Homebrew (brew) requires the contents of `/usr/local` to be owned by you. You can fix it easily by running:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```

from your Terminal.

See [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/9953#issuecomment-3800557) for further explanation.

Comment: Actually chown doesn't work for me. I use 'chmod 777 /usr/local/share/man/man3' to get through. Thanks.

Comment: thanks. This solved so many issues I had with homebrew. Not sure how /usr/local got mucked up in the first place!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend on going chmod 777 as this is way insecure.

Answer (score 5):

first

```
sudo chown -R 'your name' /usr/local
```

then

```
brew link pcre -f
```

then

```
brew install watchman
```

it should work