# ERROR watchman--no-pretty get-sockname when run npm start

Tags: macos, npm, homebrew, react-native

i know this error has been solved. I followed everything uninstall then reinstall. update and upgrade. run `npm r -g watchman`... but all fail when try to run `npm start`

I suspect because my `LaunchAgents` on macbook has been interrupted. this is what I get when run

`ls -ld ~/Library/LaunchAgents`

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 infacq  staff  46 Aug 16 11:03 /Users/infacq/Library/LaunchAgents -> /usr/local/opt/mysql/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

anyone experience this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to:

```
rm /Users/infacq/Library/LaunchAgents
```

You may also need to:

```
mkdir /Users/infacq/Library/LaunchAgents
```

but you may need to fix the permissions on that dir so that others cannot write to it

Comment: i'm not familiar to set the permissions. Would you elaborate this? If I install any other stuff from brew, will it become normal again?

Answer (score 1):

Same as the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35018487)

Try reinstalling watchman:

```
npm r -g watchman 
brew update && brew upgrade
brew install watchman
```

I had to reinstall libtool as well

```
brew reinstall libtool --universal && brew unlink libtool && brew link libtool
```

If you get a permission error during the libtool process while trying to do the following

```
brew link pcre 

Error: Could not symlink share/man/man3/pcre.3
/usr/local/share/man/man3 is not writable.
```

Then you'll need to update your permissions as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319378/cant-link-pcre-thru-brew-in-max-os-yosemite)

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```