# unable to run npm start for react-native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my first attempt at running react-native project. Followed all the instructions mentioned at react-native side. and ran 'npm start' 
Getting below error in command prompt :

```
     ERROR  watchman--no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code null dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Reason: image not found

Error: watchman--no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code null dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Reason: image not found

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/z013mrq/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/sane/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:198:18)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try reinstalling watchman:

```
npm r -g watchman 
brew update && brew upgrade
brew install watchman
```

If that doesn't fix it, try the answers [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323252/brew-doctor-dyld-library-not-loaded-error-no-available-formula-for-zlib).

> Try to re-install libtool by:
>
> `brew reinstall libtool --universal && brew unlink libtool && brew link
>   libtool`
>
> If won't help, try to remove it completely and re-try above
>   again:
>
> `brew uninstall libtool`

Comment: Same issue on Linux; instead of brew, install it from the official git. Instructions are in Facebook's *Getting Started* guide.